# Laravel/Eloquent - position of newQuery constraints in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

By adding the following code snippet to an Eloquent Model I can force the Model to include certain SQL constraints on all database calls ever being made using that Model:

```php
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    // Make use of all functionalities of the "newQuery" method of the
    // parent Eloquent class; and add constraints to that instance.
    $sql = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);

    // Example constraint
    $sql->where('example', 'test');

    return $sql;
}
```

However, when adding constraints in e.g. the controller, those additional constraints will always be added AFTER the above `` WHERE `example` = 'test `` constraint.

Is it possible to force a certain constraint AFTER all other constraints are added? Instead of BEFORE? I have this need to comply with the order of existing database indexes.

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.2?  Check out global scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes) to implement this functionality, not overriding the `newQuery` method.

Second, if your only concern is index usage, the position of columns in the where clause does not matter for index selection. The order of the columns in the index definition matters, but not the order in the where clause.